# Ssh without password to Embedded read only device

Tags: linux, ssh, embedded

I want to be able to retrieve values from an embedded device every minute. Currently I have a script that does this over ssh but I have to type in the password for the embedded device every time I connect to it over SSH. The embedded device is read only and there is absolutely no way I can mount it as writeable at this time. The embedded device is configured badly so I can't even temporarily upload the id_rsa.pub of my machine to the embedded device to allow me to automatically connect using public key authentication. The other problem is I can also not use the "expect" keyword or sshpass daemon since I can't install software on the embedded device.

I forgot to say there is another read only embedded device between me and the embedded device with the data on.

Is there any hope for me?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: could also use `expect` scripting language or something like `sshkit` in ruby to automate the connecting and retrieval from the device, what lang in current script written in.

Answer (score 0):

`expect` is to be run not on the embedded but the system you're logging in from.

Comment: I forgot to say there is another read only embedded device between me and the embedded device with the data on.

Comment: Well, you gotta learn how to input pass for the port forwarding through it, then. )

Comment: So I can open a tunnel and just try keeping it open instead of having to connect over and over again?

Comment: Sure you can do it that natural way. )